# Chrome debugger showing wrong values

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, for-loop, google-chrome-devtools

I was debugging my js code on Chrome Ubuntu (Version 68.0.3440.106 64 bits) and I notice that the debugger is giving me wrong values, even if I watch the value by adding a watch expression entry.

```
for (let i = 0; i < visibility.show.or.length; ++i) {
   const currentVisibilityContext = visibility.show.or[i];
}
```

[image: i can not be undefined]

but if I use `var` instead of `let` it works fine

```
for (var i = 0; i < visibility.show.or.length; ++i) {
   const currentVisibilityContext = visibility.show.or[i];
}
```

Can any one explain to me this behavior?
Thank you very much.

Comment: It's not clear from your description what exactly is incorrect and what exactly was expected. Depending on that, the observed behavior is either caused by an internal optimization of the code or it's a bug in devtools.

Answer (score 0):

Variables declared with the var keyword can not have Block Scope.

Variables declared inside a block {} can be accessed from outside the block.

Example

```
{ 
    var x = 2; 
}
// x CAN be used here
```

Before ES2015 JavaScript did not have Block Scope.

Variables declared with the let keyword can have Block Scope.

Variables declared inside a block {} can not be accessed from outside the block:

Example

```
{ 
    let x = 2;
}
// x can NOT be used here
```

copied without problems from W3schools ofc

Comment: So if you use **let**, i is unaccessible.

Comment: I agree that the variables declared with let are block scoped. There is no problem with the code, it runs without any bug, the problem is with chrome debugger. Check the break-point it's inside the for loop but it show "i" as undefined.

Comment: what does it return if you ask for visibility.show ? what is inside the object? or is it just **{show: {...}}** ?

Answer (score 0):

That's so weird. I get this when a console snippet is fired.
[image]

Is any of the properties of visibility, a `observable` property (like a KO observable) by any chance. Probably the debugger stepped into the observable property viz, function and is out of scope. Since everything is in one line, you get to see that debugger is executing a single command. Please try to split the line into multiple lines, to see how it behaves.

Comment: what's your OS and Chrome version?

Comment: Version 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Win 10

Comment: i tried in my desktop where I run 68.0.3440.106 chrome and the behavior is same